# Change C++ structure to JSON string using python

Tags: python, c++, json, python-3.x

Is there any way to convert an c++ structure to JSON string using Python?

I have multiple c++ files that contain structure for example as following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    float salary;
};
```

I want to convert it to JSON string. so I can use JSON string in my python project.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You'd need values for this to be a valid JSON object. Anyway just remove the `struct Person` line and replace the `;` with `,` and you're almost done

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a standardized format and there are libraries for neraly every common programming language that will help you with that.

I am not sure what exactly you are asking; do you really want to convert a c++ file (containing a c/c++ structure) with Python? There are c++ libraries which can do that for you, too

Read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented) about c++ and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a C++ struct to JSON string, there are a lot of libraries to do that. In my example, I am using https://github.com/nlohmann/json

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json.hpp"
using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    int age;
    float salary;
}; 

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.name = "Shivam";
    p.age = 7;
    p.salary = 45.0;
    // creating json
    json j;
    j["name"] = p.name;
    j["age"] = p.age;
    j["salary"] = p.salary;
    string s = j.dump();
    cout<<s<<endl;
    // pretty print
    cout<<j.dump(4)<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't initialize fields in c++ project. I have 90 structs. and how do I get this json string in my python project?

Comment: Could you add details to the question? Like expected inputs and desired outputs.